# Problems with printer connection HP PSC 500 to Dell Latitude D610 running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, dell, hp

HP PSC 500 to Dell Latitude D610 running Ubuntu 14.04.  Shows "connected to local host", jobs show up in print queue, nothing prints, jobs disappear from queue. Is there a way to troubleshoot this?  I'm new to Ubuntu, have searched and searched here and referred links. Thanks for your help!

I see these messages, but don't understand them:
Printer state: idle - rendering completed
and
HP PSC 500, hpcups 3.14.3 Idle